# How to check output after FPGA Implementation?

Tags: fpga, verilog, virtex-series-fpga

I have 10 numbers saved in RAM. I sorted it using Verilog code and  saved output in another RAM. I did simulation and it was doing correct sorting. I synthesized it and generate bit file. Now i want to see whether it performing logically fine after FPGA Implementation or not.But i am confused how will i get output sorted data after FPGA implementation.

Please suggest me how will I get output data after FPGA implementation so that i can check it manually and sure that my CODE is right with FPGA too.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

- You can use ChipScope. That's an on-chip logic anaslyzer, which is synthesized into your design.
- You can implement (or use) a FPGA to PC communication like UART to write numbers and read results.
- You can implement a testcase in hardware (like your testbench) that enlights a LED if the testcase is passed.
- ...

Comment: I took the third approach and it works for me . Thank you